# how can I change the hsperfdata default dir?

Tags: jvm, monitor

My Java Version

> java version "1.8.0_91" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_91-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Start Java Process with such command:
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/root -XX:+UsePerfData Test

Code Like this:

```
    public static final int jvmPid() {
    try {
      RuntimeMXBean runtime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
      Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
      jvm.setAccessible(true);
      VMManagement mgmt = (VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
      Method pidMethod = mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
      pidMethod.setAccessible(true);
      int pid = (Integer) pidMethod.invoke(mgmt);
      return pid;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return -1;
    }
  }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
      String property = "java.io.tmpdir";
      String tempDir = System.getProperty(property);
      System.out.println("OS current temporary directory is " + tempDir + " pid is " + jvmPid());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      count += 1;
      if (count >= 10) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

The hsperdata still in /tmp dir, why?

Comment: Don’t post your actual question as a comment. [edit] the question and put the actual question at the beginning or adapt the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change location of `hsperfdata` directory with a JVM option.
It's [hard-coded](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/735f9fd6dbe0/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp#l1568) to be `/tmp`.

However, if you run the JVM in a separate mount [namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) (read "container"), you may [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) `/tmp` to a different directory.

Comment: Thank you very much; why use hard code in 1.8? I do not think it is a good code in jdk

Comment: @WeiLiu Utilities like `jps` and `jstat` rely on hsperfdata. They search for a file in a known location. If the directory is changed, `jps` and `jstat` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that the code is using environment variables to find out where the temporary directory is, such as `$TEMP` or `$TMP`. You could try changing those as well; not all code uses the `java.io.tmpdir` system property (though they should).

Comment: I use the file (hsperfdata_${user}/${pid})  to monitor  other process jvm capacity or used, however, it is too easy to be deleted, cause it's in tmp dir; So I want to change the default dir with setting "java.io.tmpdir"; But It does not work;

Comment: I misread the original question and you were talking about the `hsperfdata` which is generated by the JVM in native code, which is why it doesn't use Java properties to set. So my answer is incorrect; unfortunately I can't down-vote it.